# How to write a function that count the total points in python?

Tags: python

How to write a function that count the total points according in python?

For example,

```
      rank_list=[['Peter','Amy','John','Kitty'],['Amy','John','Kitty','Peter']]
```

People get 5 points for first ranking, 2 points for the second, 0 point for the third and 9 point for last.

I want a list that count the total point of people

Answer (score 3):

Does this work for you?

```
In [277]: rank_list=[['Peter','Amy','John','Kitty'],['Amy','John','Kitty','Peter']]

In [278]: points = collections.defaultdict(int)

In [279]: for rank_lis in rank_list:
   .....:     for score, person in ran
random     range      rank_list  
   .....:     for score, person in enumerate(rank_lis[::-1]):
   .....:         points[person] += score
   .....:         

In [280]: points.items()
Out[280]: [('Amy', 5), ('John', 3), ('Kitty', 1), ('Peter', 3)]
```

A more efficient solution:

```
In [285]: rank_list=[['Peter','Amy','John','Kitty'],['Amy','John','Kitty','Peter']]

In [286]: for rank_lis in rank_list:
    for score, person in enumerate(rank_lis, -3):
        points[person] -= score
   .....:         

In [287]: points.items()
Out[287]: [('Amy', 5), ('Peter', 3), ('Kitty', 1), ('John', 3)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `defaultdict`: -

```
rank_list=[['Peter','Amy','John','Kitty'],['Amy','John','Kitty','Peter']]
my_dict = {0:3, 1:2, 2:1, 3:0}   # Have a mapping from index to score

from collections import defaultdict

ranking = defaultdict(int)

for elem in rank_list:
    for index, value in enumerate(elem):
        ranking[value] += my_dict[index]

print ranking.items()
```

**OUTPUT : -**

```
[('Amy', 5), ('Kitty', 1), ('Peter', 3), ('John', 3)]
```

Comment: +1 for a correct solution, but this doesn't scale. What happens if there are `N >> 3` ranks? You'd have to write a very large `my_dict`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget.. Yeah, in that case, we would have to create that rank dict from the `given` dict before proceeding. But, your 2nd way is better than this. :)

Comment: Assuming the points are linear (pos 0 gets n points, pos 1 gets n-1 points, pos n gets n-n = 0) you can use arithmetic instead of a dictionary. `ranking[value] += (max_score - index)`

Comment: @Tim.. Oh that would be a better way. Thanks Tim. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a reverse list as an index (since 0 = 3, 3 = 0, etc.), and saving to a dictionary:

```
d = {}
for list in rank_list:
  for name in list:
    if name in d:
      d[name] = d[name] + list[::-1].index(name)
    else:
      d[name] = list[::-1].index(name)
```

`list[::-1]` outputs the list in reverse.  Also, you can then get the scores by printing `d['Peter']`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a job for [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

rank_list=[['Peter','Amy','John','Kitty'],['Amy','John','Kitty','Peter']]
rank_by_place = (3, 2, 1, 0)

ranks = Counter()
for record in rank_list:
    for name, rank in zip(record, rank_by_place):
        ranks.update({name: rank})

print ranks.most_common()  # ordered by rank
```